# How to exclude certain .CSS file from output in Webpack:?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

```
foo.js
foo.css
bar.css
```

`foo.js` includes `foo.css`.
And `foo.css` includes `bar.css`.

As result, I have bundle with `bar.css`. I want to exclude it. I am also using `MiniCssExtractPlugin` since I nee to separate css and js files.

What I already tried:

- `IgnorePlugin`. It removes `bar`, but then `MiniCssExtractPlugin` fails because of it.
- `null-loader` for `bar.css` ( I tried both `test` with regexp and include/exclude). It simply doesn't work (it could be that I miss something.
- Two `oneOf` rules for `/\.css$/`: for with `null-loader` and another with everything else.

Nothing works.

What is the correct way to achieve it?

My `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/bar\.css$/)
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

And the output

```
ERROR in ./src/foo.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module '-!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./bar.css'
```

It seems that `MiniCssExtractPlugin` uses `css-loader` explicitly, so I can't skip module loading with configuration.

Comment: Can you include your `webpack.config.js` please?

Comment: can you try `new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/bar\.css$/);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude some css files in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297105/exclude-some-css-files-in-webpack)

Comment: @DacreDenny I added it.

Comment: @DerekLawrence I tried, please check updated version of question

Comment: Whats the reasoning for excluding this css file when foo uses this? It seems that something inside their requires that file when the loader is loading it.

Comment: @Derek Lawrence this file is not mine, it is one of external dependencies, and it contains code that I don't need

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` to replace bad file with empty one

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const pluginToIgnore = /bad_css\.css$/;
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({}),
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
            pluginToIgnore,
            '!./empty.css'
        )
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: trying to do the same but replacing scss files but its not working.